# Angular - Add a list of elements inside div when I clic in an element

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'd like adding a list of tecnologies inside a div when I click in an element p.
I have added a reference in html code to select inside component of Angular with the property Viewchild.
I have created the function "desplegar()" to create the list and insert inside of div.
The list is inserted but always in the same div.

The action would be the next:

1. Clic in the label p and the function desplegar() is executed.
2. This function inserts the list inside of div where the button was clicked.
3. Each div inserts his own list when you click in his button.

CODE:
[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBv87.png)
[COMPONENT TS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OrWX.png)

***I think the problem is the variable 'listadoTec' because is general and it should be especific of this.**

Someone have any idea?

Thanks!!

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
[create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Eberot, it's better is you paste the snippets of code, as "code" sections in your question instead of images, so it can be quoted more easily.

Comment: Of course, no problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
 <div *ngFor="let info of formacion; let i=index" class="elemento animate__animated animate__fadeIn">
      <div class="cuerpo">
           <p class="fecha">{{info.fecha}}</p>
            <h3 class="titulo">{{info.titulo}}</h3>
            <p>{{info.escuela}}</p>
            <p *ngIf="info.url" class="linkSite"><strong>URL: </strong> <a [href]="info.url">{{info.url}}</a></p>
             <div *ngIf="info.tecnologias" class="tecno" #listadoTec (click)="desplegar($event, info.titulo, info.tecnologias)">
               <p>Tecnologías</p>
              </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

**ANGULAR COMPONENT TS:**

```
export class FormacionComponent {

    // Declarar variable
    formacion:Formacion[]=[];
    cursos:Formacion[]=[];

    //Inicializar el servicio
    constructor(private formacionService:formacionService ){
    this.formacion=this.formacionService.formacion;
    this.cursos=this.formacionService.cursos;

    }

  //Seleccionar elemento por etiqueta
  @ViewChild('listadoTec') listadoTec!:ElementRef;

    desplegar(event:any, infoTitulo:any, tecnologias:any){

      let listadoTec = this.listadoTec.nativeElement;
      
      var listadoTecnologias = document.createElement("ul");
      listadoTecnologias.className="listaTec";
      listadoTecnologias;
      listadoTecnologias.style.padding="0";      
      listadoTec.appendChild(listadoTecnologias);

      let datosTecnologias = tecnologias.toString();
      const tecnologiasArr = datosTecnologias.split(",");
      console.log(tecnologiasArr);
      let styleEtiquetas = "display:inline-block;background:var(--blueeb);padding:0.5em;margin:0.5em 0.25em;font-size:0.85em;border-radius:5px;";
    
      for (var i = 0; i < tecnologiasArr.length; i++) {
       
        var elementosCat = document.createElement("li");
        elementosCat.style.cssText=styleEtiquetas;
        elementosCat.appendChild(document.createTextNode(tecnologiasArr[i]));
        listadoTec.appendChild(elementosCat);
      }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).